# extract day and month from datetime Series without apply

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following `Series` and want to extract the day of the `datetime`.

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.Series(pd.bdate_range('2017-05-01', '2017-05-05'))
```

So far, the only solution I can think about is using `apply` method:

```
dates.apply(lambda x: x.day)
```

However, I noticed that for large `pandas dataframe`, the `apply` method is not super fast. In a previous code as an example, I had to convert a `timedelta` in days and used `.astype('timedelta64[D]')` instead of `.apply(lambda x: x.days)`, increasing significantly the speed of my code.

I was wondering if anybody had an idea of what I could do to avoid the `apply` method for my `datetime Series` to extract the `day` of my `datetime`. Also, if possible, not too specific as I would like to do the same to extract the `month`.

Comment: use `dates.day` or `dates.dt.day`

Comment: `dates.day` won't work, but `dates.dt.day` does, thanks

Comment: I didn't see the series ctor, without it you get a datetimeindex for which dates.day would've worked

Comment: you are right, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`dt` accessor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor):

```
In [11]: dates.dt.day
Out[11]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
dtype: int64
```